# How do I bind a value for a CQL timestamp column using the Cassandra Java driver?

Tags: java, cassandra

I am unable to bind the Timestamp value in java. I tried typecasting the and use the bind().set(index, new Timestamp(value), Timestamp.class) but it didn't work. Any other way to achieve this ?

Note: I am using datastax library for prepared statements.

Comment: Could you please update your original question and post a minimal sample of your code plus the CQL query you're executing and any errors you're getting? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In the Java driver docs for [Prepared statements](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.13/manual/core/statements/prepared/), there is an example for specifying the timestamp in a `BoundStatement` using the `setQueryTimestamp()` method:

```
BoundStatement bound =
  ps1
      .boundStatementBuilder()
      .setString(0, "324378")
      .setString(1, "LCD screen")
      .setExecutionProfileName("oltp")
      .setQueryTimestamp(123456789L)
      .build();
```

If you update your original question and provide an extract of your code with an example of your query and errors you're getting, I'd be happy to look at it. Cheers!